# How to save sessions in browser

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, firefox-for-android

I use [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en) browser session manager chrome plugin quite heavily on desktop and I want similar functionality on android.

I know chrome does not have plugin support on Android. So I tried bunch of plugin on firefox. I was able to install almost all plugins on Firefox Android. However none worked at actual functionality of saving sessions. Some simply had UI malfunctioning while saving sessions, other simply threw error.

Has someone tried successfully saving browser sessions on Android?

**Edit**

- Seems that [Tabboo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/tabboo-session-manager/?src=search) plugin is working. But still I will welcome any recommendations, as it does not let us import, export sessions. Ok, it seems to be buggy. We cannot open saved sessions. Can only delete url from session, rename session name, cant open session, cant open url from session.
- Also tried [tabSession](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/tabsessions/?src=search), Saving sessions and opening them working. But it shows only name you gave to the session while saving in its UI. So UI is just a list of names of sessions. It does not show URLs within each session.
- Just came to know we can use kiwi browser on android which can install extensions from chrome store. I tried installing session buddy in kiwi. The extensions worked quite well, with some limitations. Able save, open, export sessions. Seems that session buddy cannot capture tabs in incognito. Also there are some UI glitches, may be since the plugin is built for desktop screen asect ratio.